# Is there any way to invoke some script or alerts in aerospike

Tags: java, aerospike

Is there any way to invoke some script or alerts in aerospike .

Eg ram utilization, node crashes, 80% capacity reached.

Any such tool references will be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Nagios with the [script provided here](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/monitor/nagios/). You may also use the [collectd plugin](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-collectd).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Boundary plugin](http://www.boundary.com/integrations/aerospike/). DataDog plugin is going to be released soon.